# How to Clear or Remove the values from List in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I wrote a Testcase, where it will read the login details from excel sheet and for each pair of details it will login and logout.

I am reading data from Excel, each row details i am passing to list and sending that as input to the another keyword/function for login.

After logout, i just want to remove the values in the list, it showed as succeeded but in next run it showed old values also.

I searched, i didn't get any keyword to clear all the list values.

Can one please help me on this. Here the code is:

```
    *** Settings ***
        Documentation     CLM Registration Test Case
        Test Teardown     Close All Browsers
        Library           Selenium2Library
        Library           Collections
        Library           ExcelLibrary
        Library           String

   *** Variables ***
    ${delay}          5s
    ${excelName}      LoginTestData.xls
    @{rowValues}
    ${rowCount}       ${EMPTY}
    ${cellCount}      ${EMPTY}

    *** Test Cases ***
    Get Data from Excel
        Open Excel Sheet    ${excelName}
        @{sheetNames}    Get Sheet Names
        ${sheetName}    Set Variable    @{sheetNames}[0]
        ${rowCount}    Get Row Count    ${sheetName}
        ${cellCount}    Get Column Count    ${sheetName}
        : FOR    ${rindex}    IN RANGE    1    ${rowCount}
        \    @{rowValues}    Get Values    ${sheetName}    ${rindex}    ${cellCount}
        \    Log to console    row values are for index ${rindex} : @{rowValues}
        \    Login to the CLM    @{rowValues}
        \    Log    cell count is : ${cellCount}
        \    Change Language to English
        \    Sleep    ${delay}
        \    Logout from CLM
        \    Remove Values    ${rowValues}    ${cellCount}

    *** Keywords ***
    Open Excel Sheet
        [Arguments]    ${excelName}
        Open Excel    ${excelName}    useTempDir=False

    Get Values
        [Arguments]    ${sName}    ${row}    ${cCount}
        Log to console    user is in Get Values function
        : FOR    ${cindex}    IN RANGE    0    ${cCount}
        \    Log to console    get the data from ${sName}[${cindex}][${row}]
        \    ${cellValue}    Read Cell Data By Coordinates    ${sName}    ${cindex}    ${row}
        \    Insert Into List    ${rowValues}    ${cindex}    ${cellValue}
        [Return]    @{rowValues}

    Login to the CLM
        [Arguments]    @{rowValues}
        Open Browser    http://172.20.24.74/clm-ui/#/login/    chrome
        Maximize Browser Window
        Sleep    ${delay}
        Input Text    id=username    @{rowValues}[0]
        Input Password    id=password    @{rowValues}[1]
        Click Button    css=.btn.btn-primary

    Remove Values
        [Arguments]    ${rowValues}    ${cellCount}
        Log to console    rowvalues are : ${rowValues} and cell Count: ${cellCount}
        : FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    0    ${cellCount}
        \    ${value}=    Remove from List    ${rowValues}    -1
        \    Log to console    value removed from list is : ${value}

    Change Language to English
        Sleep    ${delay}
        Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//*[@id='top-navbar']/ul[2]/li/a/span[2]    30s
        Click Element    xpath=//*[@id='top-navbar']/ul[2]/li/a/span[2]
        Click Element    xpath=//*[@id='top-navbar']//a[contains(text(),'English')]

    Logout from CLM
        Sleep    ${delay}
        Click Element    xpath=//*[@id='top-navbar']/ul[2]/li/a/span[2]
        Click Link    link=Logout
```

In the output it showed as value removed, but next run, it showed old values also

out put as below:

```
===========================================================================================================
ReadExcel :: CLM Registration Test Case                                                                    
===========================================================================================================
Get Data from Excel                                                                                user is in Get Values function
get the data from LoginDetails[0][1]
get the data from LoginDetails[1][1]
row values are for index 1 : [u'akurasa', u'Srija210$']
rowvalues are : [u'akurasa', u'Srija210$'] and cell Count: 2
value removed from list is : Srija210$
value removed from list is : akurasa
user is in Get Values function
get the data from LoginDetails[0][2]
get the data from LoginDetails[1][2]
row values are for index 2 : [u'clmui', u'tecnotree', u'akurasa', u'Srija210$']
rowvalues are : [u'clmui', u'tecnotree', u'akurasa', u'Srija210$'] and cell Count: 2
value removed from list is : Srija210$
value removed from list is : akurasa
| PASS |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the keyword "Create List" as the last step of  FOR loop instead of  "Remove Values" user defined keyword. Also, move the variable ${cellCount} inside the loop if number of columns varies for each row

```
    Get Data from Excel
    Open Excel Sheet    ${excelName}
    @{sheetNames}    Get Sheet Names
    ${sheetName}    Set Variable    @{sheetNames}[0]
    ${rowCount}    Get Row Count    ${sheetName}

    : FOR    ${rindex}    IN RANGE    1    ${rowCount}
    \    ${cellCount}    Get Column Count    ${sheetName}
    \    @{rowValues}    Get Values    ${sheetName}    ${rindex}    ${cellCount}
    \    Log to console    row values are for index ${rindex} : @{rowValues}
    \    Login to the CLM    @{rowValues}
    \    Log    cell count is : ${cellCount}
    \    Change Language to English
    \    Sleep    ${delay}
    \    Logout from CLM
    \    @{rowValues}    Create List
```

"@{rowValues}    Create List": This command will clear the values in the list

Comment: Hi Rakesh, sorry i didn't get you, what functionality i have to implement in  "Create List" user defined keyword.

Comment: "Create List" is a library keyword which is available in BuiltIn library. You don't need to write any script for it. Just copy and paste the above script in Test case section. Try it and update.

Comment: `Clear List` is no longer available. Link to documentation as of feb 13, 2024: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.1.2/libraries/Collections.html#Remove%20Values%20From%20List

Answer (score 1):

In my case the list what I wanted clear was global, so i couldn't clear it with Create List. In this case a

```
:FOR     ${elem}    IN    @{list}
    Remove values from list    ${list}    ${elem}
```

helped.